# Database and internal server error after docker-compose

Tags: docker

I inserted a new service (just a python script) into docker-compose.yml file.
After that I did a `docker-compose up --build -d` command to build and run the containers.

After do that, the webserver was giving a database error and a internal server error if I don't start the database container.

What can be if the service that I add was previously running into other computer with docker and the docker-compose file was correct?